# Azure API Management - how to enable HTTP/2 via PowerShell command?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-api-management

I'm looking for the correct PowerShell syntaxt to enable HTTP/2 setting for an Azure API Management instance.
[image]

I'm assume somehow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/new-azapimanagementsslsetting?view=azps-3.4.0) (`New-AzApiManagementSslSetting`) one, but

a) what is the exact syntax and

b) can I also enable it for an exiting instance (like you can do in the portal)?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/New-AzApiManagementSslSetting?view=azps-3.4.0

Comment: It has examples about how to use it so what exactly is your question about the syntax

Comment: it doesnt show how to enable http2. The only sample is for some TLS protocol. Also it does not explain how to enable this on an existing instance. As any APIM deployment takes at least 45min, this is not a great place for trial and error. Hence my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason the PowerShell command did not work for me, so I did this with bash (and jq). First modify the customProperties and store it in a variable:

```
customPropertiesNew=$(az apim show -n $APIM_NAME -g $APIM_RG --query customProperties | jq '."Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Protocols.Server.Http2" = "True"')
```

Then apply your modified customProperties (this step can takes 7-14 minutes!):

```
az apim update -n $APIM_NAME -g $APIM_RG --set customProperties="$customPropertiesNew"
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you wan to assign http2 to the front/backend vs at the ServerProtocol as shown in the docs?  --- Why are you not just doing...

```
$enableHttp2 = @{'Http2' = 'True'}
```

Along with what Mohammad already pointed you to, which shows the Http2 setting on the -[ServerProtocol parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/New-AzApiManagementSslSetting?view=azps-3.4.0)...

> -ServerProtocol Server protocol settings like Http2. This parameter is optional.
>
> Type: Hashtable Position: Named Default value:    None Accept pipeline
>   input:    False Accept wildcard characters:   False

[the settings docs, specifically say ...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/release-notes-azureps?view=azps-3.4.0)

Updated cmdlet New-AzApiManagement to manage ApiManagement service
Added support for the new 'Consumption' SKU
Added support to turn the 'EnableClientCertificate' flag on for 'Consumption' SKU

***The new cmdlet New-AzApiManagementSslSetting allows configuring
'TLS/SSL' setting on the 'Backend' and 'Frontend'.***

***This can also be used to configure 'Ciphers' like '3DES' and 'ServerProtocols' like 'Http2' on the 'Frontend' of an ApiManagement service.***

Added support for configuring the 'DeveloperPortal' hostname on ApiManagement service.
Updated cmdlets Get-AzApiManagementSsoToken to take 'PsApiManagement' object as input